# What is a UEFI?

Tags: bios, ubuntu-12.04, uefi

While installing ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my windows 8 PC, many online tutorials were telling to disable the UEFI.
My question is what is UEFI and what is it's use?

Comment: Before asking further questions, please read [ask] and do a little more research.

Comment: @slhck I appreciate your suggestion,  but could you point out what is wrong in the above question, that prompted other users to downvote it.

Comment: It does not show any research effort at all. You could have had a look at the Wikipedia page for UEFI, for example. If you have a *specific* question about something you didn't understand while reading about UEFI, then it would have been a proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UEFI is the new BIOS.

If you don't know what the BIOS is, it's a small program built into your computer that runs the boot process, and displays any Setup menus.  UEFI is more (some would say too much) capable - some UEFI boards have elaborate graphical setup menus now and such.

UEFI introduces a feature called "Secure Boot" where it will only boot an OS that is "signed" with one of the keys in the UEFI.  Microsoft is using this on Windows 8 tablets and PCs.  You cannot install another OS unless you disable Secure Boot.

You actually can, but you need to install your own keys into the UEFI and use a bootloader that works with it.  Some UEFI's are locked and don't allow changing the UEFI secure boot setting, namely Windows RT tablets.  The security benefits of UEFI's Secure Boot are debatable - if you don't know about or use full disk encryption, UEFI's Secure Boot won't benefit you too much.

Answer (score 1):

The [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface), or Unified Extensible Firmware Interface is a standard to replace the aging BIOS firmware in most computers.

The EFI is the boot environment and firmware level that does the POST check, boots the OS, and finally (can) provide services such as time, video, and other serivces to OSes that have not loaded their drivers yet.

Answer (score 0):

The Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) is a specification that defines a software interface between an operating system and platform firmware.

UEFI is meant to replace the Basic Input/Output System (BIOS) firmware interface, present in all IBM PC-compatible personal computers. In practice, most UEFI images provide legacy support for BIOS services. UEFI can support remote diagnostics and repair of computers, even without another operating system.
New Windows PCs come with UEFI firmware and Secure Boot enabled. Secure Boot prevents operating systems from booting unless they’re signed by a key loaded into UEFI